# Mongoose/Mongodb getting .deleteOne is not a function

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I click to delete a post, my console is saying `TypeError: post.user.posts.deleteOne is not a function`. It giving me this error after deleting.

`const post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(id).populate('user');` This code I am deleting the post from Post Schema

`await post.user.posts.deleteOne(post)`This code is to delete the post from the User Schema. I populated user and assigned it to `post` and then delete the user's post from this code, but I'm getting the error here.

Below is the controller code

```
export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;


    try {
        const post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(id).populate('user');
        await post.user.posts.deleteOne(post)

        if (!post) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: "Unable To Delete" })
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted Successfully" })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Client side delete request

```
const handleDeleteTrue = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await api.delete(`/post/${id}`)
            console.log(data)
            window.location.reload();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data.message);
        }
    };
```

User model schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unqie: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    },
    posts: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post", required: true }]
});

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Im able to delete the post from the post model schema, but in this pic, which shows the user model schema, that same post that was deleted is not deleted here. This is the problem Im trying to solve.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I can seem to understand in your function below is that you're trying to delete a single post and also checking if post exists first

```
export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;


    try {
        const post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(id).populate('user');
        await post.user.posts.deleteOne(post)

        if (!post) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: "Unable To Delete" })
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted Successfully" })
     catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you try this

```
export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    try {         
        //check if document exists in mongoDB collection
         if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Unable To Delete" })    }

        await Post.deleteOne(id)

        res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted Successfully" })
     catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to delete 2 things. I have a user model schema and a post model schema in which both schema has a `post` object. Im able to delete the post from the post model schema but not from the user model schema. The user schema has an array of post that the user created, so when I delete the post from the post schema, I also want to delete the same post from the user model schema. Hope that make sense...

Comment: I added a picture for your reference to look at

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. My user model schema for post was an array so I had to use $pull to delete it.
This is the code that worked for me

```
        await post.user.posts.pull(post)
        await post.user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use findOneAndDelete on populate to delete one object from an array. it doesn't work that way. Use This Instead.

```
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: Id },
      { $pull: { post:PostId } },
      { new: true }
    );
```

You can find More on Pull and Push Operations on [BlogLink](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/mongodb-push-pull/)